# Error download file from subdomain in php?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

`<a href="www.demo.simple.com/file.zip">download</a>`

=> result (download from `www.demo.simple.com`)

But when I using:

```
$url = 'www.demo.simple.com/file.zip';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

header("Content-type: application/zip");
echo $result;
```

=> result download from `www.simple.com`
I don't know why using code php download a file from sub domain `www.demo.simple.com` is popup show info download from from `www.simple.com`

Comment: Do you have the real URLs you can share? Maybe it is redirecting based on the user agent PHP is sending and check the headers that are returned

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the protocol otherwise the domain would appear to be a path under the current domain -> add http://

Try:

```
http://www.demo.simple.com/file.zip
```

Also, in order to force it to download as a file instead of displaying in page (such as downloading pdf rather than browser displaying the pdf), add the following header.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
```